# Restrict editors to only able fill today's date in data validation date - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, data-validation, google-sheets-data-validation

I have used the data validation date > 'valid date' so that in the range of cells I want, will already show the calendar drop down. However, would like to ask for guidance on how I can restrict the editors to only able to pick today's date & tomorrow, but not the date before today or the date after tomorrow.
Would really appreciate the help.